# Spring Oauth2 RemoteTokenServices error on extractAuthentication

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a resource server and an auth server.

On resource request it verifies the received access_token with the auth server on a `/oauth/check_token` endpoint. This gives a response that makes my request crash.

The response is sent as:

```
Written [{exp=1433335640, scope=[read, write], authorities=[ROLE_USER], client_id=client-w-s}] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@58a88f5a]
```

When my resource server receives it:

```
2015-06-03 14:17:48.277 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : POST request for "http://localhost:6707/oauth/check_token" resulted in 200 (OK)
2015-06-03 14:17:48.277 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading [interface java.util.Map] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@67409450]
2015-06-03 14:17:48.283 ERROR 9492 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.ArrayStoreException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultAccessTokenConverter.extractAuthentication(DefaultAccessTokenConverter.java:139)
```

This is the piece of code it fails on:

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = null;
if (user==null && map.containsKey(AUTHORITIES)) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    String[] roles = ((Collection<String>)map.get(AUTHORITIES)).toArray(new String[0]);
    authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(roles);
}
```

I ran in debug mode to check the values in `map`, and everything looks like I think it should judging from the response my auth server built.

Please tell me if I need to post more information.

Has anyone experienced this or have any clue on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "solution".

There was a version mismatch in my pom files. While my auth server was running `spring-security-oauth2-2.0.5.RELEASE` my resource server was running `spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE` .

The versions declare the response differently.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in DefaultAccessTokenConverter implementation, since spring-security-oauth2 2.0.7.RELEASE, because of this line:

if (**user==null** && map.containsKey(AUTHORITIES)) {
...
}

Why the "**user==null**" condition?
The "user" variable isn't null, so the condition is never true, and the authorities array is not filled.

I think this is a Spring Security Oauth2 implementation error.